# Twitter bootstrap dropdown menu doesnt work when deployed

Tags: jquery, grails, twitter-bootstrap

My app works perfectly in development but when I deploy it on tomcat drop down menu stops working. It's there and it drops down on mouse over but its not reacting on mouse click. I've checked generated links and the look fine. If I manually enter URL it works fine. I'm guessing it's some JavaScript/file location problem but I cant seem to find it. Probably missing something obvious.

Here is my main.gsp where I generate my menu:

```
<!doctype html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title><g:layoutTitle default="Grails"/></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="${resource(dir: 'images', file: 'favicon.ico')}" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="${resource(dir: 'images', file: 'apple-touch-icon.png')}">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="${resource(dir: 'images', file: 'apple-touch-icon-retina.png')}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'main.css')}" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'mobile.css')}" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css/bootstrap', file: 'bootstrap.css')}" type="text/css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="<g:resource dir="/js/bootstrap" file="bootstrap-dropdown.js" />"></script>

    <g:layoutHead/>
    <r:layoutResources />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <a href="http://grails.org">
            <img src="${resource(dir: 'images', file: 'coming.gif')}" alt="Grails"/>
        </a>
        <sec:ifLoggedIn>
            <div id="headinfo">
                <g:message code="header.user" /> :  ${ sec.loggedInUserInfo(field:'username') }  <br/>
                <g:message code="header.date" /> : <g:formatDate date='${new Date()}' format='E, dd MMM yyyy' locale='${Locale.ENGLISH}'/> <br/>
                <a href="?lang=sr"> <g:img dir="images" file="sr.gif"/>  </a>
                <a href="?lang=en"> <g:img dir="images" file="en.gif"/>  </a>
            </div>
        </sec:ifLoggedIn>
        <h2 id="maintitle"><g:layoutTitle default="Grails"/></h2>
    </div>

    <header class="jumbotron subhead" id="overview">
        <div class="subnav">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills" id="meni">
                <li class="dropdown open">
                    <a href="${createLink(controller:'ticket',action:'index')}"> <g:message code="menu.home" /> </a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown open">
                    <g:link controller="ticket" action="list" data-toggle="dropdown"> <g:message code="menu.tickets" /> <b class="caret"></b> </g:link>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li> <g:link controller="ticket" action="list" data-toggle="dropdown"> <g:message code="menu.ticketList" /> </g:link> </li>
                        <li> <g:link controller="ticket" action="create" data-toggle="dropdown"> <g:message code="menu.createTicket" /> </g:link> </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>


                <li class="dropdown open">
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown"> <g:message code="menu.admin" /> <b class="caret"></b> </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li> <g:link controller="user" action="list" data-toggle="dropdown"> <g:message code="menu.listUsers" /> </g:link> </li>
                        <li> <g:link controller="company" action="list" data-toggle="dropdown"> <g:message code="menu.listCompanies" /> </g:link> </li>
                        <li> <g:link controller="company" action="create" data-toggle="dropdown"> <g:message code="menu.createCompany" /> </g:link> </li>
                        <li> <g:link controller="project" action="list" data-toggle="dropdown"> <g:message code="menu.projectsList" /> </g:link> </li>
                        <li> <g:link controller="project" action="create" data-toggle="dropdown"> <g:message code="menu.createProjects" /> </g:link> </li>
                        <li> <g:link controller="user" action="invitation" data-toggle="dropdown"> <g:message code="menu.inviteUser" /> </g:link> </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <sec:ifNotLoggedIn>
                    <li class="dropdown open">
                        <g:link controller="login" action="index" data-toggle="dropdown"> <g:message code="menu.login" /> </g:link>
                    </li>
                </sec:ifNotLoggedIn>
                <sec:ifLoggedIn>
                    <li class="dropdown open">
                        <g:link controller="logout" action="index" data-toggle="dropdown"> <g:message code="menu.logout" /> </g:link>
                    </li>
                </sec:ifLoggedIn>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>


    <div id="maincontent">
        <g:layoutBody/>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar-inner" id="footerdiv">
        <div id="foottext"> Help Desk </div>
    </div>

    <div id="spinner" class="spinner" style="display:none;"><g:message code="spinner.alt" default="Loading&hellip;"/></div>
    <g:javascript library="application"/>
    <r:layoutResources />

    </div>
</body>
```

And here is a page head:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title><g:layoutTitle default="Grails"/></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="${resource(dir: 'images', file: 'favicon.ico')}" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="${resource(dir: 'images', file: 'apple-touch-icon.png')}">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="${resource(dir: 'images', file: 'apple-touch-icon-retina.png')}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'main.css')}" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'mobile.css')}" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css/bootstrap', file: 'bootstrap.css')}" type="text/css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="<g:resource dir="/js/bootstrap" file="bootstrap-dropdown.js" />"></script>

    <g:layoutHead/>
    <r:layoutResources />
</head>
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
This is the only error in Chrome console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) http://sg.perion.com/v1.1/js/gt.js
```

And I've noticed that if I open a dropdown menu link with right_mouse_button/open_in_new_tab it works.

Comment: What browser are you using? Depending on which the javascript console might be a good place to start.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Sorry. Error in pasting.

Comment: @JonasStensved Mostly Chrome.

Comment: Take a look at the [console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console) and see if there's any reported errors and if your files are loaded

Comment: I've just noticed that menu works if I open menu links with right mouse_button_click/open_in_new_tab

Comment: Why aren't you using ${resource(dir: 'js/bootstrap', file: 'bootstrap-dropdown.js')} for bootstrap-dropdown.js??

Comment: Why aren't you using resources? Holy...

Answer (score 0):

You need to have valid Doctype. Make sure your .gsp and generated page source starts with:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<g:resource dir="/js/bootstrap" file="bootstrap-dropdown.js" />"></script>
```

To

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<g:resource dir="js/bootstrap" file="bootstrap-dropdown.js" />"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [Grails Bootstrap plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/twitter-bootstrap). This should handle the inclusion of all necessary bootstrap files.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to MVC and Bootstrap and had this issue when under Bootstrap 3.3.5 I modified bootstrap.css to restore the submenu class, but had not modified bootstrap.min.css. All was well in Dev where compilation Debug=True (web.config -->system.web) and minified files are ignored, but when deploying to the server where Debug=False the minified version (bootstrap.min.css) was overriding my customized version. As a short term fix I deleted the bootstrap.min.css file in Production but will now investigate updating the minified .css file. Definitely a rookie mistake but there are a few of us out there and I hope this helps someone else.